# What to use to get the whole file size of a partially downloaded mp4?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, mpeg-4

I tried with ffmpeg and MediaInfo, both give me only the downloaded size. MediaInfo also gives me the stream sizes, but audio+video is still ~130kb smaller than the original final size. What can I use for that?

Comment: info why do you need this would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

mp4 file like almost all other file types doesn't contain info about its size. usually it's sum of its streams + size of metadata. I believe metadata size can vary